# How to plot shape at the end of time on the Renko candle Chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I want to plot shapes at the end of the Renko Candle close at 30min timeframe. But It only plots at the start of the time interval.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Renko Brick Close', overlay=true)

res = input('30')
isnew = ta.change(time(res)) != 0

plotshape(isnew)
```

How to plot shape at the end of that period and not on the beginning. Is it possible to do that without `request.security` and `offset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use barstate.isconfirmed it will only plot a shape once the candle has closed

for example, this would plot an arrow either up or down on every candle other than the real time candle

```
closeup = close > open
closedown = close < open

plotshape(closeup and barstate.isconfirmed, 'close up', shape.arrowup, location = location.belowbar)
plotshape(closedown and barstate.isconfirmed, 'close down', shape.arrowdown, location = location.abovebar)
```

Comment: Thanks. but `barstate.isconfirmed` plots shapes on all the Renko bricks. But I want it at the last brick in the particular timeframe.